# How to use the error return by API which shown in network memory of browser?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to print the error returned by my nodeJs API. 
I am hitting the API with following code :

```
this.http.post<any>(this.dataService.base_url+"/event/login", data,  options).pipe(
            catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log(error);})
```

This prints "Unprocesseble entity" as post is not able to get data on console. But my API return "User Not Found" which is shown in below image. I am able to see that error return by API in browser network memory but I cant use it in Application.

[image: Chrome Browser network tab]

Comment: What are you getting in your console.log?

Comment: "Unprocesseble entity" that is error of post method if we call API with wrong credentials.

Comment: try replacing your console.log with this : console.log(HttpErrorResponse)

Comment: @rahim.nagori  HttpErrorResponse(init) {
        var _this = 
        // Initialize with a default status of 0 / Unknown Error.
        _super.call(this, init, 0, 'Unknown Error') || this;
        _this.name = 'Htt…